# AWS lambda function:put event is not triggered in direct browser upload in php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3, lambda

I've successfully created a lambda function that resizes an image and stores into a bucket in s3(bucket name:`cropped`).
Also this lambda function invokes when a file is uploaded into another bucket(bucket name:`source`).

When i upload an image through aws console into the `source` bucket the AWS lambda function is triggered and the cropped image is created in `cropped` bucket.

But when i try with programmatic file upload ( s3 browser file upload) the lambda function is not triggered(cropped image is not creating in `cropped` bucket) however the image is successfully uploaded into `source` bucket.

**Browser file upload**

```
<form id="upload" action="//s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/lambdacushbu" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="Content-Type" value="multipart/form-data" />
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="private" />
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_status" value="201" />
<input type="hidden" name="policy" value="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" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-credential" value="AKIAJRVEARQ/20170324/us-west-2/s3/aws4_request" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-date" value="20170324T054410Z" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-amz-signature" value="854ea7ec0c456c03509d22a6de39b045e54b71a779af8d88175717d8b54ccebc" />
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}" />
    <input type="file" name="file" id="image">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="upload" name="upload">
        <span id="status-text"></span>
        <img src=""  id="cropped-image">
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

I've tried with normal file upload method ie user uploads file to my server and then it put into aws s3 bucket.
Now its working

So i think there is an issue with direct browser upload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i resolved the issue for the browser direct uploads the events is `POST`

For enabling

1.Go to s3 console and select the bucket.

2.Go to properties select **Events** and add a new event with `POST`

Create the event with post and choose your lambda function that you want to invoke and save.